# Automorphisms of Upper Half Plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

A colleague tried convincing me that both $f(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ and $g(z)=\frac{z}{z+i}$ are automorphisms of the upper half plane of $\mathbb{C}$. I really doubt it, especially because I can't convert them to the $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ forms, where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ad-bc=1$.

Comment: $f(i) = 0$ and $g(i) = 1/2$, so that cannot be automorphisms of the upper half plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your colleague is wrong ! Compute $f(1+i)$ and $g(1+i)$. Both values are not in the upper half plane .

Answer (score 1):

$f(i) = 0$ and $g(i) = 1/2$ shows that these are not automorphisms of the upper half plane.

But you have
$$
 f(z) = i T(-i z) 
$$
where $T(t) = \frac{z-1}{z+1}$ is an automorphism of the upper half plane.

It follows that $f$ is an automorphism of the right (and left) half plane.

A similar argument applies to $g$.